# how to routing in asp.net and change address

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

i have one address:

```
http://www.testsite.com/List.aspx/Category-cat1/Category-cat2/Brand-18
```

how to when click on link, user route to address:

```
http://www.testsite.com/Search/Category-cat2/#/Category-cat1/Category-cat2/Brand-18/
```

i want to route users to this address to users don't know main address name of page (in this example, List.aspx)

and i want to find final category which request from user.
in this example, i want to get Category-cat2.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for URL rewriting. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) is a very good blog which describes how to achieve it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL rewriting.like

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/testsite/(.+).aspx" to="~/testsite.aspx?category=1" />
  </rewriter>
```